# Adding a number at the beginning of a string

Tags: python, arrays, loops, split, io

i am trying to read strings from a line and add a number at the beginning of each string and add each into an array, however my code adds a number to EACH character of the string.

```
infile = open("milkin.txt","r").readlines()
outfile = open("milkout.txt","w")

number = infile[0]
arrayLoc = infile[1].split( )
array = infile[2].split( )

for i in infile[2]:
    counter = 1
    countered = str(counter)
    i = countered + i
    array.append(i)

output:
['2234567', '3222222', '4333333', '5444444', '6555555', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '1 ', '12' .... etc

intended output:
['12234567', '23222222', '34333333', '45444444', '56555555']
```

---

```
infile:
5
1 3 4 5 2
2234567 3222222 4333333 5444444 6555555
```

Comment: There are no characters as such in Python. Any character is a one-character string. Your question does not make sense. Please clarify (perhaps by example) what you _expect_ and what you _get_ instead.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. i have clarified the problem, and provided an example of what i need.

Comment: You're looping over the wrong thing. `for i in infile[2]:` should be `for i in array:` - of course once you make that change, the `array.append(i)` won't make any sense. Forget the loop entirely, and do this instead: `array = [str(i) + x for i, x in enumerate(infile[2].split(),1)]`

Comment: If the answer provided helped, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the `array` that you read from your file, and since it looks like you want to add sequential numbers to each element, you can use `enumerate(array)` to get the index of each element as you loop. You can add an argument to `enumerate` to tell it what number to start at (default is 0):

```
new_arr = []
for i, a in enumerate(array, 1):
    # 'i' will go from 1, 2, ... (n + 1) where 'n' is number of elements in 'array'
    # 'a' will be the ith element of 'array'
    new_arr.append(str(i) + a)
print(new_arr)

['12234567', '23222222', '34333333', '45444444', '56555555']
```

As pointed out in a comment, this  can be done much more concisely using a list comprehension, which is the more pythonic way to loop:

```
new_arr = [str(i) + a for i, a in enumerate(array, 1)]
```